# SPOJ AGS runtime error

Tags: c

I was practising dynamic programming on [SPOJ](http://www.spoj.com). I am stuck on this problem named [AGS](http://www.spoj.com/problems/AGS/). Below is my code. It is giving runtime error on SPOJ but is running perfectly fine on my computer. Please help

```
#include<stdio.h>

long long mypow(long long base,long long exp,long long mod,long long log[])
{
    if(log[exp]!=0)
        return log[exp];
    if(exp==0)
        return 1;
    if(exp==1)
        return base%mod;

    long long ans = ((base%mod) * mypow(base,exp-1,mod,log))%mod;
    log[exp]=ans;
    return ans;

}

long long gpsum(long long r,long long k,long long mod,long long log[])
{
    if(k==0)
        return 1;
    if(k==1)
        return 1+r;

    long long ans=(mypow(r,k,mod,log)+gpsum(r,k-1,mod,log))%mod;
    return ans;
}
int main()
{
    long long i,t,k,a,d,r,n,mod,p,q,ans;
   scanf("%lld",&t);

 while(t--)
 {
       scanf("%lld %lld %lld",&a,&d,&r);
       scanf("%lld %lld",&n,&mod);
       long long log[n/2];
       for(i=0;i<n/2;i++)
        log[i]=0;


    if(n==1)
    {
        ans=a;
    }
    else if(n%2==0)
    {
    k=(n-2)/2;
    p=mypow(r,k,mod,log);
    q=gpsum(r,k,mod,log);
    ans=(((p%mod)*(a%mod))%mod+((q%mod)*(d%mod))%mod)%mod;
    }
    else
    {
    k=(n-3)/2;
    p=r*mypow(r,k,mod,log);
    q=r*gpsum(r,k,mod,log);
    ans=(((p%mod)*(a%mod))%mod+((q%mod)*(d%mod))%mod)%mod;
    }

    printf("%lld\n",ans);
 }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What runtime error? and on what input?

Comment: On the testcases that spoj checks.. I just submitted the solution.

Comment: Could it be that the input your program is expecting is not exactly the same the SPOJ providing?

Comment: I think no,I've checked it many times.

Comment: Try it on ideone.com. I think they are using the same engine..

Comment: I've already tried. Its also giving the same error

Comment: And what is that "AGS"-problem? Make your question complete!

Comment: Link is there. Click on AGS in the question

Comment: So try to debug it on ideone and deduce the line that is causing the error. Not so difficult.

Comment: Its running and displaying the correct answer for the sample inputs.. Its not working for the testcases that spoj provides. i.e it is not working for input sizes of 10^8.

Comment: Can you provide some input that is not working?

Comment: 1 12345678 12345678 12345678 12345678 12345678

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the line `long long log[n/2];` causing the error. For `n = 12345678` (from the sample input in the comments) it will try to allocate around 6M of `long long` which is about 50Mb on the stack. Which is, I am guessing, too big for the online multi user compilers. The following code will prove this claim:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define MAX 7000000
int main()
{
    volatile long long v[MAX];
    long i;
    for ( i=0; i<MAX; i++ )
        v[i]=i+1;
    printf("Hello");
    return 0;
}
```

The value of `MAX` as stated will give the error on [ideone](http://ideone.com). Reducing the value, say to 700000 will remove the error (don't mind the volatile and the loop exercises, they are there to trick on optimizer).
A possible solution would be allocating this memory statically, as a global variable - outside the main function, such that it will go to the `.data` section, and not to the stack. This solution:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define MAX 7000000
volatile long long v[MAX];
int main()
{

    long i;
    for ( i=0; i<MAX; i++ )
        v[i]=i+1;
    printf("Hello");
    return 0;
}
```

works just fine even with larger numbers.

Comment: Hmm.. I see..Tried applying this. Still SIGEGV.. :-(